# Can't pass array and comparator as generic types

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I'm a little unschooled in generic types and was hoping for some clarification. In my Java textbook, a program for mergesort is provided for us:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class mergeSortBook{
    public static<K>void merge(K[] S1,K[] S2,K[] S,Comparator<K>comp){
        int i=0,j=0;
        while(i+j<S.length) {
            if(j==S2.length || (i<S1.length && comp.compare(S1[i],S2[j])<0))
                S[i+j]=S1[i++];
            else 
                S[i+j]=S2[j++];
        }
    }
    public static<K>void mergeSort(K[] S,Comparator<K>comp){
        int n=S.length;
        if (n<2) return;
        int mid = n/2;
        K[] S1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(S, 0, mid);
        K[] S2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(S, mid, n);
        mergeSort(S1,comp);
        mergeSort(S2,comp);
        merge(S1,S2,S,comp);
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement the above algorithm. After some research, I decided to instantiate a default comparator and pass it to the mergeSort() function. However, I ran into problems when trying to pass in an array. The error in my Eclipse IDE is `The method mergeSort(K[], Comparator<K>) in the type mergeSortBook is not applicable for the arguments (int[],mergeSortBook.DefaultComparator<Integer>)`

Below is the code for my main method and DefaultComparator method. I would really appreciate any tips on passing the right type of arguments to get the program working.

```
    public class DefaultComparator<E> implements Comparator<E> 
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(E a, E b) throws ClassCastException {
            return ((Comparable<E>) a).compareTo(b);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int arr[] = {3,1,6,2,4,8,9,2,1};
        mergeSort(arr,new DefaultComparator<Integer>());
    }
```

Comment: You can't sort `int[]` with a generic method. Only reference types work with generics, e.g. `Integer[]`.

Comment: BTW, avoid that awful cast in your comparator by specifying `DefaultComparator<E extends Comparable<E>> implements Comparator<E>`.

Comment: Instead of `DefaultComparator`, you can use `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `Integer` to use a generic method (`int` is a primitive type, and not `Comparable`). You can also use [`Comparator.naturalOrder()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--). Like,

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Integer[] arr = { 3, 1, 6, 2, 4, 8, 9, 2, 1 };
    mergeSort(arr, Comparator.naturalOrder());
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Outputs

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

Finally, instead of `Comparator<K>` the "correct" type would be `Comparator<? super K>`. And don't omit braces just because it's legal. And `S1`, `S2` and `S` aren't particularly meaningful (or helpful) variable names. They don't follow Java naming conventions looking like types. We can do better and still use short names. Like,

```
public static <K> void merge(K[] left, K[] right, K[] arr, Comparator<? super K> comp) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i + j < arr.length) {
        if (j == right.length || (i<left.length && comp.compare(left[i], right[j])<0)) {
            arr[i + j] = left[i++];
        } else {
            arr[i + j] = right[j++];
        }
    }
}
```

And if you're going to put your declarations on a single line *please* be consistent. Like,

```
public static <K> void mergeSort(K[] arr, Comparator<? super K> comp) {
    int n = arr.length, mid = n / 2;
    if (n < 2) {
        return;
    }
    K[] left = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, mid), right = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, mid, n);
    mergeSort(left, comp);
    mergeSort(right, comp);
    merge(left, right, arr, comp);
}
```

Comment: "And don't omit braces just because it's legal." If you're going to pick on style points, I'd point out that giving variables uppercased, very short names makes them look just like type variables, which makes them very hard to read in amongst the actual type variables.

Comment: I'd also point out that using arrays and generics together is a path to pain: better to use `List<K>`.

Comment: @AndyTurner "A man who carries a cat by the tail learns something he can learn no other way" - Mark Twain

Comment: What a superb quote.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort `int[]` with a generic method. Only reference types work with generics, e.g. `Integer[]`:

```
Integer arr[] = {3,1,6,2,4,8,9,2,1};
mergeSort(arr,new DefaultComparator<Integer>());
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I got this error with your suggested changes: `No enclosing instance of type mergeSortBook is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type mergeSortBook (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of mergeSortBook).`

Comment: That is completely unrelated to this change. That's simply that you've not made your comparator `static`.